What hugging model is recommended for finding terms in texts (or synonims)
I would like to use a hugging face model in order to for example find the concept "pedestrian" in a description like "In this image there is a person driving a minibike and another on a bicycle. There is also a scooter and a person."
You notice that pedestrian does not appear in the description but a person appears and that can be a pedestrian.
Another case would be to search for "moped" and there is a minibike mentioned so there is the probability of being a moped
I have so far tried a NLI-based Zero Shot text classification with a script like
from transformers import pipeline

# Load the zero-shot classification pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
# classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli", device=device)

category_name = "pedestrian"
results = "In this image there is a person driving a minibike and another on a bicycle. There is also a scooter and a person."

# Perform zero-shot classification
labels = [category_name]  # The categories you want to match with the results
prediction = classifier(results, candidate_labels=labels)

# Check if the category is predicted with high confidence
if prediction['scores'][0] > 0.7:  # Set a threshold (e.g., 0.7)
    print(f"'{category_name}' is present in the results with confidence {prediction['scores'][0]:.2f}")
else:
    print(f"'{category_name}' not found with sufficient confidence.")

But although the examples in the hugging face page work well, this one always give me a confidence of 0.0  (and even when I put the same word, the confidence is low!)
Can someone suggest an approach to solve this problem?
